# What is the most apt way to setup a RTC?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, ntp, rtc

I've gone through a plethora of sources and found it a little confusing with too much information hence posting this question.

Firstly, the scenario is, I've set up my PI-3B(jessie) with PCF8523t RTC. The PI will get connected to the internet **very occasionally**. So, therefore there are two questions I would like to get the answer for:

1. I need to know if the modifications done below are correct (please suggest which are the required/redundant steps)
2. What is best way to synchronise the **Network time to the RTC whenever the internet comes up**?
3. [NEW] Is it required to disable the NTP service?

The problem was if the PI(when not connected to internet) was showing the correct time if booted after 10 minutes, but if booted after a day, there was incorrect time shown.

**Below is the software version of the PI**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

**The following changes were made**

> 1. In the /boot/config.txt file

uncommented the **'dtparam=i2c_arm=on'** and added **'dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf8523'**

> 2. The following commands were run

```
apt-get -y remove fake-hwclock
rm /etc/cron.hourly/fake-hwclock
update-rc.d -f fake-hwclock remove
rm /etc/init.d/fake-hwclock
systemctl disable fake-hwclock
```

> 3. Commented out the following lines in /lib/udev/hwclock-set

```
#if [ -e /run/systemd/system ] ; then
# exit 0
#fi
#/sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --systz --badyear
#/sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --systz
```

> 4. Updated the (correct) system time into the hardware clock by

```
hwclock -w
```

> 5. Added the below modules to the /etc/modules file

```
i2c-bcm2708
i2c-dev
i2c-pcf8523
```

> 6. Edited the /etc/rc.local with the following lines

Ensured there is **'#!/bin/bash'** at the beginning of the script

```
sleep 2
pcf8523 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
( sleep 2; hwclock -s ) &
```

> 7. Edited the /etc/default/hwclock with

```
HWCLOCKACCESS=yes
```

> 8. Added the below as root's cronjob(done to sync the network time to RTC)

```
    */5 * * * *   ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org || ( hwclock --adjust; hwclock -s )
```

Comment: Why are you still using Raspbian Jessie? Your need to switch to Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: I am not too sure if you should do the following: "uncommented the 'dtparam=i2c_arm=on' and added 'dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf8523'"  You are disabling I2C and might cause a problem to other I2C devices.  I confess I have not studies your procedure too carefully.

Answer (score 2):

The **ONLY** thing you have to do is include in /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf8523
```

DO NOT fiddle with the software or attempt to manually synchronise - it all happens AUTOMATICALLY.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51782/8697

If you need to set the RTC initially (if NTP not available) you can use `hwclock --set` see `man hwclock` for details.

Comment: As per your suggestion removed everything, the only changes done are `sleep 2 && hwclock -s` in /etc/rc.local file and uncommented `HWCLOCKACCESS=yes` and `HCTOSYS_DEVICE=rtc0` in /etc/default/hwclock, and still I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Manoj How is this following my suggestion "DO NOT fiddle with the software or attempt to manually synchronise"?

Comment: Yeah I tried removing the command from rc.local and that too failed. Keeping that command in rc.local had a much better success rate so I retained it

Answer (score 0):

***Questions***

> 1. How to sync Network time to the RTC?
> 2. How to use PCF8523RTC dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf8523RTC

***Answers***

> 1. After booting, you can use the following python statements to sync Network Time, then update PCF8523.

[image: python to update time]

> 2. The best reference I can find about ***linux hwclock*** is the one listed in the reference below.  It describes how linux, on booting,
>      sets system clock from hardware clock.  You need to make clear the
>      hardware clock, system clock, and even Section 9.1 fake-hw_clock.
> 3. I would suggest to update from Jessie to stretch, for two reasons: (1) What you read from archLinux about hwclock might be applicable to
>      jessie, but not stretch.  (2) Many drivers work in jessie might not
>      work for stretch, because the driver author retires and no longer
>      support os upgrades.  That is why I always avoid DTO (dtoverlay) and
>      rely on python.  I wrote my little simple python driver for RTC DS3231
>      and found my effort is worth it.  I have not used PCF8523.  Perhaps I
>      should later take a look an update my answer here.

***References***

[PCF8523 Datasheet - NXP](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCF8523.pdf)

[Adafruit PCF8523 Real Time Clock](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pcf8523-real-time-clock/overview)

[DS3231 vs DS3231 Benchmarks](http://Benchmarks:%20RealTime%20Clocks%20%E2%80%93%20DS3231%20/%20PCF8563%20/%20MCP79400%20/%20DS1307)

[RTC comparison - 2017feb03](http://blog.dan.drown.org/rtc-comparison/)

[WaveShare's DS3231 RTC Module 6 Step Setup Guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1347276&hilit=DS3231%20tlfong01#p1347276)

[DS3231 RTC Simple Setup Functions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&hilit=DS3231%20tlfong01&sid=fcef721933d68e5ee0f973bae684e2b1&start=275#p1349014)

[How do I fix incorrect timestamps in my bash script that launches on startup?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99232/how-do-i-fix-incorrect-timestamps-in-my-bash-script-that-launches-on-startup)

[hwclock (Time) - archLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time)

> In an operating system, the time (clock) is determined by four parts:
>
> time value, time standard, time zone, and Daylight Saving Time (DST)
>   if applicable.
>
> This article explains what they are and how to read/set them.

*Two clocks are present on systems:*

> a ***hardware clock*** and
>
> a ***system clock*** which are also detailed in this article.

*Standard behavior of most operating systems is:*

> Set the system clock from the hardware clock on boot.
>
> Keep accurate time of the system clock...
>
> Set the hardware clock from the system clock on shutdown.

*Contents*

> 1 Hardware clock
>
> 1.1   Read hardware clock
>
> 1.2   Set hardware clock from system clock
>
> 2 System clock
>
> 2.1   Read clock
>
> 2.2   Set system clock
>
> 3 Time standard
>
> 3.1   UTC in Windows
>
> 3.2   UTC in Ubuntu
>
> 4 Time zone
>
> 5 Time skew
>
> 6 Time synchronization
>
> 7 Per-user/session or temporary settings
>
> 8 Troubleshooting
>
> 8.1   Clock shows a value that is neither UTC nor local time
>
> 9 Tips and tricks
>
> 9.1   ***fake-hwclock***
>
> 10    See also, ...

***Update 2019jun12hkt1050***

I googled comparisons of DS3231 with PCF8523 and my quick conclusion is that they are both good for hobbyists projects.  DS3231 modules has the advantage that there is ***a temperature sensor built into the chip and an EEPROM built into the module***.  So I would prefer DS3231.

[image: ds3231 vs pcf8523]