# How to know if time is synced?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, c, systemd, ntp

I'm writing a software in C and it is running as a `systemd` service. I need the service to run after time has synced or alternatively, I need a way for my C program to identify if time has synced.

I'm not using GPS or RTC. Just the plain Raspberry (both Zero W and 3B+).

I'm using Raspbian Strecth. I was trying to use `time-sync.target` but it still call my service before date/time is synced.

How can I detect if system has updated its time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timedatectl` will show if synced

```
               Local time: Tue 2019-11-19 09:59:09 AEDT
           Universal time: Mon 2019-11-18 22:59:09 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Australia/Sydney (AEDT, +1100)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

`/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock`   shows last synch time (NOTE this is a zero length file - look at the timestamp)

May be `/var/lib/systemd/clock` on older Debian OS

NOTE Raspbian Stretch **DOES NOT use ntpd**

Comment: I was able to manage it with timedatectl. Thank you. Regarding `/var/lib/systemd/clock`, I don't know what to compare it with, to determine if system has synced or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you install `ntpd` instead of `timesyncd`, you can check out the first line of the output of [`ntpstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpstat):

```
$ ntpstat | head -n1
unsynchronised

... later on ..

$ ntpstat | head -n1
synchronised to NTP server (10.5.26.10) at stratum 2
```

Inside a script or a C program, use the return code:

> ntpstat returns 0 if clock is synchronised. ntpstat returns 1 if clock is not synchronised. ntpstat returns 2 if clock state is indeterminant, for example if ntpd is not contactable.

Answer (score 2):

Since `systemd 239` there is a **systemd-time-wait-sync.service** available that you can just use in your systemd service to start `After=systemd-time-wait-sync.service`. For further information look at [How can I delay the startup of systemd services until the datetime is set (no RTC on the Raspberry Pi)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95195/79866). **Raspbian Buster** comes with `systemd 241`.

The problem is that you use old-stable **Raspbian Stretch** which comes with `systemd 232` so the nice time wait service isn't available in that version. For this situation you can look at the journal for a message about time syncing. I have made a service for this so you can also use it to start `After=` it. You will find it also at [How can I delay the startup of systemd services until the datetime is set (no RTC on the Raspberry Pi)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94651/79866).